# SQL Server Management Studio Express not showing recently added data 

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

I recently installed and have been using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 9.00.4035.00 to manage a remote database on my hosts' SQL Server 2005.

Until now I had been using EMS SQL Manager 2011 Lite and that was working fine.

2 new rows where inserted into one of my tables this morning; one by a customer signing up for a service and the other as a test signup by me.

When I run a typical select query:

```
[Select top 20 * From tblNotary Order By ID Desc]
```

I don't see the the 2 most recent rows. But when I run the same query from EMS SQL Manager Lite I see the records.

I also verified when connecting using MS Access 2010 I see the 2 new rows in the table. I have checked and double-checked the connection settings and they match EMS.

Is there a setting or something obvious I am missing? Why can't I see the most recent record insertions? I am on a Windows 7 desktop machine.

Comment: Probably totally redundant, but are you accessing the correct database through SSMS? If you might be executing the query in the context of a test database, it could explain the difference.

Comment: I checked and double checked, but I can check again to be 120% sure.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is you are connecting to a different database than you expected.  You can [`select @@servername`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx) to verify both queries are running against the same server.

If the records are stil being inserted as part of an open transaction and have not been committed, they are called "phantom" rows.  You will not see phantom rows if your query runs at [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) `read committed` or higher.  It may be that EMS SQL Manager Lite is running at `read uncommitted`, in which case it will include phantom rows in the query.

Comment: Thanks Paul, can you help me with finding out how to check which transaction isolation level the query runs at or is there a way to specify it in the query?

Comment: I just followed the link you posted. Since this is a shared server I will not be able to set the transaction isolation level correct?

Comment: This is a setting per connection.  The default for each connection is `READ COMMITTED`.  Any client can change the current connection setting by calling `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL`.  I was speculating the the EMS SQL Manager Lite changes the level when you run a query on it.  It probably has its own setting for default isolation level; SQL Server Management Studio does in Tools/Options, Query Execution/SQL Server/Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes connection strings are a tricky thing.  Run this to double check:

```
select @@servername servername, name, crdate  
from sys.sysdatabases 
where name = db_name()
```

if you have an issue running that, just do a simpler version:

```
select @@servername, db_name(), @@version
```

Comment: The first query errored with: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.sysdatabases'. The 2nd one worked with the results: Column 1: NULL, Column 2: notaryb_notarybids, Column 3: Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.2039 (Intel X86)   May  3 2005 23:18:38   Copyright (c) 1988-2003 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select top 20 * From tblNotary Order By ID Desc
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!